# How to fix this strftime() Error

Tags: php

I wasn't getting the error yesterday, but now I am so not sure what happened

`Warning: strftime() [function.strftime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.`

The code I'm using is:

```
$date = (isset($_GET['country']) && ($_GET['country'] == 'KE' || $_GET['country'] == 'PH' || $_GET['country'] == 'US')) ? strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : strftime("%d/%m/%Y");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "en_US");
```

I'm trying to display the date of the in whatever country the visitor is in

Comment: Set your timezone in the .htaccess, php.ini , etc.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy will that work for visitors in other countries? I don't want the date to be based off of the servers time/date, I want it to be based on the visitors time/date

Comment: Yes, you are required to set the time zone based on the server location - the rest will fall into place.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly delcare the timezone.

httpc.conf/.htaccess:

```
SetEnv TZ Country/City
```

php.ini

```
date.timezone = Country/City
```

Comment: will this work for the visitors time/date? I want the date in the local country to display